# Can't convert tuple list to hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap, tuples

I want to convert a `javax.persistence.Tuple` into a `HashMap`, but like this, it inserts the last element of the tuple and takes also the alias and data type. How can I improve this method so it takes values of the tuple?

```
public Map<String, Object> tuplesToMap(List<Tuple> data){
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    data.forEach(tuple -> {
        tuple.getElements().forEach(
            element -> {
                values.put(element.getAlias(), tuple.get(element));
            }
        );
    });
    return values;
}
```

Comment: you are talking about javax.persistence.Tuple, aren't you?

Comment: @luca.vercelli yes

Answer (score 5):

with java 8 is simply :

```
return data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        t -> t.get(0, String.class),
        t -> t.get(1, Object.class)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working :

```
public static List<Map<String/*UPPERCASE*/, Object>> jpaTuplesToMaps(
  List<javax.persistence.Tuple> data
){
    return data.stream()
        .map(tuple -> { // per each tuple of the input List
            // creating a new HashMap
            Map<String, Object> resultItem =  new HashMap<>();
            // filling the created HashMap with values of
            tuple.getElements().forEach( // each column of the tuple
                col -> { resultItem.put(col.getAlias(), tuple.get(col)); } 
            );
            // returning the created HashMap instead of  the current Tuple
            return resultItem;
        })
         // collecting & returning all the created HashMap-s as a List
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But usualy both single & list conversions are required, so let's combine them :

```
public static Map<String/*UPPERCASE*/, Object> jpaTupleToMap(
    javax.persistence.Tuple data /*CASE INSENSITIVE*/
){
    Map<String, Object> result = 
        new HashMap<>(); // exactly HashMap since it can handle NULL keys & values
    data.getElements().forEach(
        col -> { result.put(col.getAlias(), data.get(col)); } 
    );
    return result;
}

//-------------------------
    
public static List<Map<String/*UPPERCASE*/, Object>> jpaTuplesToMaps(
    List<javax.persistence.Tuple> data /*CASE INSENSITIVE*/
){
    return data.stream() // List<Tuple> -> Tuple1,..TupleN
        .map(tuple -> jpaTupleToMap(tuple)) // Tuple1 -> HashMap1,..TupleN -> HashMapN
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // HashMap1,..HashMapN -> List
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `element.getAlias()` you're using as the key for the hashmap is probably same for some of the elements.

`Map` keys are unique, meaning, if you insert entries (1, "one") and then (1, "two"), the first value will be overridden by the latter. If you want to have multiple values mapped to one key, use `Map<String, Collection<Object>>`, or a `Multimap` from Guava, which is exactly the same thing.

You can insert into multimap with this function - if the key is not in the map, create a new `ArrayList` and add it to the map, otherwise return the existing one. Then, insert the value to the list:

```
values
    .computeIfAbsent(element.getAlias, k -> new ArrayList<>())
    .add(tuple.get(element));
```

Comment: If I do it like that I get Incompatible type for tuple.get(element)

Comment: Yes, you also need to create the collection you put the elements to - you changed the values in the map from `Object` to `Collection<Object>`

Comment: You can do that, of course, in that case you would have `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead of `Map<String, List<Object>>` - just keep in mind that map keys are unique, and it is up to you to ensure that you do not overwrite the existing mapping.

Comment: I agree with @OndraK. I just underly that a ``List<Tuple>`` is, in fact, a matrix, or also a table. So it's not reasonable to transform it into a ``Map<String, Object>``, which is a single row of the table. It's more reasonable to transform it into a ``List<Map<String, Object>>``.

Answer (score 0):

**You can convert List of Tuple to HashMap**

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

for (TupleElement tupleElement: listOfObject.get(0).getElements()) {
map.put(tupleElement.getAlias(),listOfObject.get(0).get(tupleElement.getAlias()));
}